# How to show the HTTP request in a Jersey TestNG test?

Tags: java, jersey, testng, jersey-2.0

I am writing some Jersey TestNG tests. For debugging purposes I'd like to see the actual requests that TestNG runs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JerseyTest` provides `enable(...)` method, that gives you control over configuring values of the properties defined and described in the `TestProperties` class.

```
public class MyTest extends JerseyTestNg {

    // rest omitted

    protected Application configure() {

        // rest omitted

        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
    }
```

The snippet above enables test traffic logging as well as dumping the HTTP message entity as part of the traffic logging.

See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e15711) for more details.